# Adding javascript to wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress

I am new to wordpress. I need to create a website using wordpress so i need to add javascript file to wordpress themes..

For example what i want is the background color of header will be change when i scroll the page of my wordpress site.. For that i use javascript but its not worked for me..

I used like that below,

**functions.php**

```
function my_theme_enqueue_script() {
wp_register_script( 'scrolldown' , get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/scroll.js' );
  wp_enqueue_script( 'scrolldown');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_script' );
```

**scroll.js**

```
$(window).on("scroll", function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() > 50) {
        $(".site-header").addClass("active");
    } else {

       $(".site-header").removeClass("active");
    }
});
```

**style.css**

```
.site-header {
      height: 100px;
      width: 1200px;
      transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
      z-index:10000;
      margin-left:-90px;
      position:fixed;
      background-color: transparent;
      margin-top:-70px;  
}
.site-header.active { 
     background: #353535 !important;
}
```

I don't know what I did wrong.. Can anyone help me to solve my problem..

When i go to console, I have this window below screen shot,

[image]

Comment: Have you got any error in console?

Comment: my header should be transparent even when I scroll..

Answer (score 0):

**STEP 1:**

in your functions.php replace this:

```
function my_theme_enqueue_script() {
wp_register_script( 'scrolldown' , get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/scroll.js' );
  wp_enqueue_script( 'scrolldown');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_script' );
```

with this:

```
function my_theme_enqueue_script() {
wp_enqueue_script( 'scrolldown' , get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/scroll.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0.0', true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_script', 50, 0 );
```

**STEP: 2**

in your `scroll.js` replace this:

```
$(window).on("scroll", function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() > 50) {
        $(".site-header").addClass("active");
    } else {

       $(".site-header").removeClass("active");
    }
});
```

with this:

```
(function($){ 
$(window).on("scroll", function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() > 50) {
        $(".site-header").addClass("active");
    } else {

       $(".site-header").removeClass("active");
    }
});
})(jQuery)
```

Comment: i just changed my answer reload plz @Preethi

Comment: check your `javascript` and `css` code, that you add in `style.css` and `scroll.js` file. your logic is wrong somewhere. now script is enqueuing well, only your code is not working as expected, so please check your own custom code.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/634d6vgq/2/   I used this link for reference.. Can you see this and help me..

Comment: maybe you are using a cache plugin, go clear all the cache from it, as well as clear your browser cache, open a private tab (incognito window) and load your website

Comment: @Preethi once again i changed my answer, i hope be this will work for you, pay attention to the `step 1` of my answer

Comment: @Preethi You're not helping much. Are you getting any JS errors in your console when trying to view your site? (Press F12, and reload the page). This answer is all you need to apply a JS file to your Wordpress site. PLease give us more information about what you're seeing.

Comment: In my style.css file, i give the header background will be transparent and postion fixed(.site-header) That only I am seeing in my site.. My header is fixed and transparent even I scroll also.. No change in that when I scroll.. I don't get any error also..

Comment: What I want is when i scroll the site, the header background is replaced from transparent to black or some other color what I specify.. When I go to the top position again it returns to the transparent background..

Comment: I sent the screenshot what i got in console